# Apache 2.4 .htaccess PHP Not Working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have spent my whole day trying to make this work, and I cannot make it happen.

I have a server with GoDaddy where I test websites I create. I am trying to work on a friendly-url system with htaccess, and it will not work.

The file is saved on the folder eureka
It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule trips/([0-9]+) trip_details.php?trip_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

When someone goes to http://www.jseeh.com/eureka/trips/22 I want them to be redirected to http://www.jseeh.com/eureka/trip_details.php?trip_id=22

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you're omitting the `eureka` directory. try something like this and see if it works

```
RewriteRule ^/eureka/trips/([0-9]+)\/? eureka/trip_details.php?trip_id=$1 [L]
```

Edit: New answer based on OP's reply below. Tested and working on Apache with your directory setup.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /eureka

RewriteRule trips/([0-9]+)\/? trip_details.php?trip_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work. The htaccess file is inside the `eureka` directory, so in theory, the word "eureka" is not required

Comment: Thank you so much, Tim! It was the `MultiView` that did the trick. I am not sure why, but it know works. The problem I know have is that the webpages take a very long time to load this way. Any idea why?